# Combo-Box value not passing in AJAX

Tags: ajax

Want to pass 4 values in AJAX parameter.First three are passing properly but the fourth one giving problem.i came to know after displaying alert in AJAX

```
<tr align="left">
                                    <td style="background-color:#1569C7;color:white;font-weight:bold;font-size:110%;border-style:outset;"><center><b>Test Conducted</b></center></td>
                                    <td><select onchange="javascript:type123(document.getElementById('fodate').value,document.getElementById('todate').value,document.getElementById('product').value);" id="testcond" name="testcond">
                        <option>--Select--</option>

                </select></td>
                                </tr>
```

AJAX CODE:

```
<script language="javascript">
            var xmlHttp1=null;
            function type123(obj,obj1,obj2)
              {
            //alert(this.value);
            var type_value=document.getElementById('testcond').options.selectedIndex.value;
            var val1=obj;
            var val2=obj1;
            var val3=obj2;
           // var val4=obj3;
            alert(val1);
            alert(val2);
            alert(val3);
            alert(type_value);
```

Comment: The `onchange` attribute already places you in a scripting context. You do not need to prefix your event handler with `javascript:`

Comment: Never said it would, otherwise I would have posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instend of

```
var type_value=document.getElementById('testcond').options.selectedIndex.value;
```

You can try this one to get selected value of Combo-Box

```
var type_value=document.getElementById('testcond').value;<br/>alert(type_value);
```